# How to run maven project with bat file

Tags: java, maven, batch-file, selenium-webdriver

I have converted my automation project with maven dependencies will running it with `pom.xml` the script is executing well. But while using `.bat` file to run the script I'm getting the error.

Can anyone help me out?

**`.bat` file command:**

```
java -cp bin;jars/* org.testng.TestNG testng.xml
```

**The error which I'm getting is in the image:**

[image: in the image]

Comment: Please post the error message as **text** in your question and [format](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) code properly!

Comment: @aditya If TestNG & Maven is installed & Configured properly you dont have to take help of .bat file. Maven plug-in takes care of all. Can you provide more info as: 1. Provide the testng.xml 2. Provide pom.xml 3. Provide the error you are facing.

Comment: Why do you need a bat file for calling `mvn clean package`?

Comment: are you running the command in the right directory? Maybe your project is in a different location & you are running the command in different location

Answer (score 1):

call mvn clean

call mvn package

Note that you don't need semicolons in batch files. And the reason why you need to use call is that mvn itself is a batch file and batch files need to call each other with call, otherwise control does not return to the caller.

Comment: what would be the actual command for the bat file can you please tell

Answer (score -1):

Invoke Maven from the project folder (where your pom.xml file is) with:

```
call mvn dtest
```